# View file through HREF with Password in PHP

Tags: passwords, href

I have listed out the Image/PDF files in my server to website through HREF links. When I click a link on the page it will show the Image/PDF file directly on the browser. 
But I want to set a password.
After I click the link it should ask the password, then it will show the file on the browser.
Can anyone share your info on this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This pertains to web-server configuration. Probably best to ask this at another Stack-Exchange site (say, ServerFault?)

Comment: But I need a PHP code for this issue.